# racket - define-struct and abstract list function

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a function `games-won` that consumes a list of Games, results, and a string, name, and produces the number of `games` in results that `name` won.

For example:

```
(define-struct game (winner loser high low))
(check-expect (games-won (list (make-game "Lori" "Troy" 52 34)
                         (make-game "Mary" "Lori" 30 20)) "Lori") 1)
```

Below is what I have so far:

```
(define (won? game name)
  (equal? (game-winner game) name))

(define (wonlst results)
  (filter won? results))

(define (lst-length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  0]
    [(cons? lst)   (+ 1 (length (rest lst)))]))

(define (games-won results)
 (cond
   [(cons? (wonlst results)) (lst-length (wonlst results))]
   [else 0]))
```

Can anyone help correct the errors in my code and maybe tell me how to use `local` and put the functions all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the fixes:

- As the test suggests, `games-won` should accept two arguments: a results list and a name. So we add a parameter - `name` - to `games-won`.
- You don't need a custom `lst-length` function, you can just use `length`. Also, `games-won` doesn't need to worry about returning `0` in the `else` case. The base case is taken care of by the list-abstractions.
- Note that `won?` takes in two inputs, but the predicate function in a `filter` only accepts one input. So we remove `name` from `won?`. Once we put `won?` in a local, it can just use `name` from the surrounding function's context.
- We put a local in `games-won` and put the two helpers - `won?` and `won-lst` - in the local.
- You should use `string=?` instead of `equal?`for since we know that `name` and `winner` field of `game` is always a String.

```
(define-struct game (winner loser high low))

; games-won : [List-of Game] String -> Number
(define (games-won results name)
  (local (; won? : Game -> Boolean
          (define (won? game)
            (string=? (game-winner game) name))
          ; wonlst : [List-of Game] -> [List-of Game]
          (define (wonlst results)
            (filter won? results)))
    (length (wonlst results))))


(define my-games1 (list (make-game "Lori" "Troy" 52 34)
                        (make-game "Mary" "Lori" 30 20)))

(check-expect (games-won my-games1 "Lori") 1)
```

We can just put everything in one function along with a lambda like the following:

```
(define (games-won results name)
  (length (filter (λ (game) (string=? (game-winner game) name)) results)))
```

#### How to use `local`

A local expression has the following shape:

```
(local [definition ...] body-expression)
```

Within the square brackets, you can put as many definitions (i.e. `define`s, `define-struct`s) as you want, and in the *body* of the local — `body-expression` — you can put any expression that may or may not use the definitions within the square brackets. The definitions are only available in the body.

From [HtDP](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_three.html#%28part._sec~3aeval-local%29), here's how we compute with locals:

- We rename the locally defined constants and functions to use names that aren’t used elsewhere in the program.
- We lift the definitions in the local expression to the top level and evaluate the body of the local expression next.